# Mutually Exclusive Events (or not)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Suppose that P(A) = 0.42, P(B) = 0.38 and P(A U B) = 0.70. Are A and B mutually exclusive? Explain your answer.

Now from what I gather, mutually exclusive events are those that are not dependent upon one another, correct? If that's the case then they are not mutually exclusive since P(A) + P(B) does not equal P(A U B). If it was P(A U B) = 0.80 only then it would have been considered mutually exclusive. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, mutually exclusive events are events that cannot occur simultaneously: they are disjoint. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $\Bbb P(A\cup B)=\Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B)=0.42+0.38=0.80$. That’s not the case here, so $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive.

In other words, your calculations and probably your reasoning are correct, but your use of terminology is not: *mutually exclusive* does not mean *independent*.

Comment: got it ! Thanks

Comment: @user1819786: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

"Mutually exclusive" and "independent" do not mean the same thing: they are different.

"Mutually exclusive events are those that are not dependent upon one another, correct?"

NO:

Two events are **mutually exclusive** if they cannot both occur. If we flip a coin, we get either a head, or a tail. We cannot get both. That is, the events are mutually exclusive.

**Independent** events are events where knowing the outcome of one doesn't change the probability of the other. Knowing that it's a sunny day doesn't tell me anything about the outcome of rolling a die. Those "events" are independent of one another.

When events are **mutually exclusive**, their probabilities add up to the probability that one event (or the other) occurs. In this case, if the $A$ and $B$ *were* mutually exclusive events, then you are correct, we would need for $P(A) + P(B) = 80$. But what we have, as you point out, is that $\,P(A)  + P(B) = 70\neq 80.\;$ So you're right that $A$ and $B$ are ***not*** mutually exclusive, and for the right reason - because $P(A) + P(B) \neq P(A\cup B)$ - though you want to be clear about the terminology you use.

Comment: Nice write up +1 :-) (caps lock)

Comment: Can we have mutually exclusive events that both don't happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your second conjecture (about $0.80$), but not in your former. Events that are not dependent upon one another are called (appropriately enough) [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_event), while mutually exclusive events cannot both occur, so are certainly dependent on one another when neither event is ["impossible"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_of_zero) (since, if one happens, then the other *is* "impossible").

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if $P(A\cap B)=0$.

Now for arbitrary $A$ and $B$, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. This should give you what you need.