# Mutually exclusive/independent events

Tags: probability, definition

I am having some conflicts with the basic definitions of mutually exclusive and independent event. I can't seem to understand the difference(or relation) between the two. Here's a statement from my text book.

> Non-impossible mutually exclusive events are not independent and non-impossible independent events are not mutually exclusive.

Can someone elaborate on this preferably using examples?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of independent and mutually exclusive?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412623/mutually-exclusive-events-or-not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Independent and mutually exclusive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332378/independent-and-mutually-exclusive)

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ and $B$ be events in the probability space $\Omega$.

> Two events are **mutually exclusive** iff $A\cap B = \emptyset$

In simpler terms, they cannot occur simultaneously.  We have the useful result that $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$ in general, which in the case of mutually exclusive events will simplify as $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)$ since $Pr(\emptyset)=0$.

An example of mutually exclusive events would be "*flipping heads on a coin*" versus "*flipping tails on a coin*" in a single coin toss.

> Two events are **independent** iff any of the following are true:
>   $$Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B)\\
> Pr(A|B)=Pr(A)\\
> Pr(B|A)=Pr(B)$$

In simpler terms, independent events have no influence on one another in terms of occurring.  For example, if you flip a coin and roll a six-sided die at the same time, the event "*the coin-flip is a heads*" is independent to the event "*the die face is showing a four*"

---

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously mutually exclusive *and* independent.

Then we have $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(\emptyset)=0$ because of mutual exclusivity, while we also have $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B)$ because of independence.

This implies $Pr(A)Pr(B)=0$.

Now, two real numbers multiplied together equals zero if and only if at least one of the numbers is zero.  That implies $Pr(A)=0$ or $Pr(B)=0$.  Thus, at least one of $A$ or $B$ is an (*almost*) impossible event (an event of probability zero).

---

By [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), if $A$ and $B$ are both events of positive probability, then $A$ and $B$ cannot simultaneously be mutually exclusive and independent.  It is possible that they are one or the other or neither, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two events $A$ and $B$, each with probabilities $>0$ ("non-impossible")

A test for independence is $P(A\cap   B) = P(A)\times P(B)$

Now *mutually exclusive*  events are such that both can't occur together, e.g. "Pass" and "Fail".
On a Venn diagram, they will be two circles with no common area, i.e. $P(A\cap B) = 0$
Thus obviously, such mutually exclusive events  aren't independent.

On the other hands, if the two events are *independent,* $P(A\cap B)$ has to be $>0$ since both $P(A)$ and $P(B) > 0$, which means there is a common area,  between the two, and they can't be mutually exclusive.